# Can I replace upgrade main breaker without changing wiring? (within panel limit)

Tags: circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I currently have a 30A main breaker in my panel for the workshop which is starting to give me grief, I've checked the panel and it's a 125A panel that says it's nominal output current is 63A (not sure why the input and out are different, anyway my question is can I replace the 30A breaker with a 63A breaker and not have to worry about any rewiring?

Comment: Where on this planet are you? What size wire is feeding the workshop from the main panel?

Comment: Remember breakers are sized according to wire size, unless you already have a mismatch between breaker and wire it’s likely that you can’t increase breaker sizes without re-wiring.  Also, where is that 63A number actually coming from? Is it on a sticker somewhere? Or did you get it via testing?

Comment: Are you saying the main panel has a 30 amp breaker feeding the sub in the shop? If so it was probably fed with #10 wire and 30 amp is the max breaker. The panel in the shop could be a 200 amp but if fed with #10 wire and a 30 amp breaker the wire size will need to be increased before the breaker size is increased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it unlikely that you would be able to put in a 63A breaker. The available size would be more likely be a 60A breaker. You also need to consider what feeds this panel and what size wire brings power to this panel.

1) If the panel is feed from the utility company via a power meter then the MAIN breaker would want to be sized according to the wire gauge from the meter and within the ratings of your panel. This would require consultation with the utility to determine what the delivery capability is in Amps.

2) If this is actually a sub-panel that is fed from a main breaker panel elsewhere on the property then there should be a source circuit breaker in that panel that protects the feed wires to the sub-panel. There would be no point to install a larger ampacity breaker in the sub-panel than what is in the main panel. If that main panel breaker is 30A for example and the connecting wiring is 10AWG then it would not be safe to update any part of the sub-panel power delivery to higher capacity without upgrading the wiring to a proper increased size and possibly changing the feed breaker in the main panel to a size that is compatible with the wiring installed.

Answer (score 1):

The job of a breaker is to protect wires and equipment downline.

Power goes from the breaker in the main panel, down a cable, to the subpanel.  Now the subpanel is obviously good for 125A.  However the wires *between* the main panel and the subpanel, different story.  It's vital that the breaker in the main panel protect that wire.

Now since breakers from 15-60 amps all cost the same, I'm pretty sure that **if you had put in larger wire, you'd have used a larger breaker**.  The fact that you used a 30A breaker tells me you used 10 AWG cable.  So you're done.

Other than running a new cable, what you can do is make sure your usage of that subpanel is *balanced*. You have two 120V legs (technically "poles") each good for 30A.  240V loads draw from both poles at once.  Make sure your loads are drawing evenly -- e.g. 25A from each leg -- not 40A from one leg and 10A from the other, because that will trip the breaker.